# Sitecore custom droplist

Tags: drop-down-menu, sitecore, sitecore7, custom-field-type, sitecore7.1

I have POC for a custom droplist in `Sitecore 7.0` but when i do absolutely the same in `Sitecore 7.1` it does not work. Basically what I have is:

1. In core db under the "field types/Custom field types" I have my custom field type pointing to the correct assembly and class.
2. In my .net project I have class `DroplistCustom` deriving `ValueLookupEx`. It has overridden `GetItems` function. Here is the code, but I don't think it is necessary because it works.

```cs
public class DroplistCustom : MultilistEx
{
    protected override Item[] GetItems(Item current)
    {
        string query = String.Format("{0}[@@templateid = '{1}' and @@id= '{2}']", this.Source, current.TemplateID, current.ID);
        this.Source = query;
        return base.GetItems(current);
    }
}
```

3, I use the new type in a template with a source like query:fast:/...

Do not focus on the query it works!

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? It returns no results or your code of `GetItems` method is not executed at all?

Comment: When I open an item in which template is used DroplistCustom, the field is visualized as single line text with no data in it instead of droplist. And yes GetItems is not executed at all.

Comment: Sitecore behaves that way if there is a typo in the class name in the field definition item. Check this once again and check for white spaces before/after class name.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be, that the SPEAK UI changes in 7.1 is messing with that field. There is a config file; \App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Speak.config.  My first choice would be to rename this file to .disabled, and see if it makes a difference.

Brian Pedersen blogs about it here: http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/disable-sitecore-speak-dialogs/

Comment: I tried intentionally to set wrong NS and assembly but sitecore doesn't care at all... Also there are no errors when I open items in the content editor which are using this field. I will try to do what you are suggesting and I will comment soon.

Answer (score 0):

Found what cause the problem. Everything works fine beside the fact that in SC 7.1 it is important to place your custom field types under the predefined folders. I moved my DroplistCustom form my folder "Custom Field Types" to "List Types" and it worked. 
Thanks for the help!